# Folder/Directory Navigation (Ubuntu 14.04 TLS)

Tags: 14.04, directory, tls

I'm completely new to Linux/Ubuntu so apologies for the rather elementary question.

Using the "save as" command, I'm trying to save e-mails (from Thunderbird) and documents (from Libre Office) to my folder directory but can only see/navigate to the first two folder levels. I have created the level two and subsequent sub-folders and permissions for all appear to be correct. Grateful for any advice on how to save/navigate to sub-folders.

Thank you in anticipation. R

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you are logged in using root privileged user. also use the command given below for searching the file name you are saving in the directory.

> find . -name "file_name.ext"

also if not able to find. update dba nd check using locate command

updatedb as root,
 then locate file_name.extfile

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Vembutech. Your prompt response is appreciated! I have since found that clicking on the "save" button in the navigation window (rather than on the folder list or "create new folder" button) opens the sub-folders. Rasko